# When does ManyToMany field get saved to the database?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-orm, django-signals

Given the (simplified) model, used within a Django Admin app:

**models.py**

```py
class Appointment(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    pianos = models.ManyToManyField(Piano, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        # Is it a new Appointment, not an existing one being re-saved?
        newAppointment = self.id is None
        try:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
            if newAppointment:
                # Returns empty queryset
                for piano in self.pianos.all():
                    print(piano)
        except:
            pass
```

I want to access 'pianos'.  If it's a newly created Appointment,
`self.pianos` returns

> <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager..ManyRelatedManager
> object at 0x7f6f875209a0>

and `self.pianos.all()` returns an empty queryset, even though the pianos are displayed in the template form that was submitted to initiate the save.

**However**, if it's an updating of an existing `Appointment`, 'pianos' returns the data as expected.

Apparently that `ManyToMany` field doesn't get saved to the db immediately when `save()` is called.  So how can I access the data as shown below?  Note that 'pianos' are not instantiated here, they already exist in the database, and only need Appointment to point to one or more of them in its m2m field, as directed from a `horizontal_filter` defined in `admin.py`.

I also tried the alternative method of using a `post_save` signal, with exactly the same result:

```py
@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Appointment)
def createServiceHistory(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for piano in instance.pianos.all():  #empty queryset
            print(piano)
```

**Update**: modified to catch `m2m_changed` instead of post_save:

```
@receiver(signals.m2m_changed, sender=Appointment)
def createServiceHistory(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    print(action)
```

But this signal isn't received.

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields) say that `ManyToMany` fields are saved using `add()` rather than `save()`, but I don't see how that would be applied in this case.

Comment: @Selcuk I've edited the question to be more clear that I'm working within models.py and with Django Admin.  So I'm confused, when would I do an .add(), since I'm not using my own forms.py?  Or when does Form.save() do the .add() for me?

Comment: @Ron [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) is triggered when a ManyToManyField on a model is updated, handling this signal would give you the Appointment after the related instances are saved

Comment: @Selcuk Substituting 'signals.m2m_changed' for 'signals.post_save' in the last code example in the question, it doesn't get triggered.  To be clear, the 'pianos' linked to in Appointment already exist as instances in the db, only the m2m table needs to get updated to point to one or more of them.   But apparently pressing Save isn't enough to get this trigger.  [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) say "Strictly speaking, this is not a model signal since it is sent by the ManyToManyField".  But that it "complements" post_save. **Complements?**

Comment: @IainShelvington  Just notifying you in case you have anything to add after my last comment.

Comment: @Selcuk Changing `sender` to `Appointment.pianos.through` does indeed cause the signal to be sent.  For the benefit of later readers, the action will be `pre_add` first, then a second signal arrives with action being `post_add` .  Only at that point is the data in this example available via:  `Appointment.pianos.all()`.  If you'll write up an answer I'll mark it accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: Just summarised the comments above into a more coherent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ManyToMany` association can not be created until both instances are saved, that's why it is not yet created while you are in the `Appointment.save() method`.

The `Form.save()` method (or the `Save` button, if you are using the Django Admin Interface) saves the `Appointment`, **then** associates it with the `Piano` instance(s) using `.add()`. In this case, you can use the [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) as @IainShelvington suggested:

> Sent when a `ManyToManyField` is changed on a model instance. Strictly speaking, this is not a model signal since it is sent by the `ManyToManyField`, but since it complements the `pre_save`/`post_save` and `pre_delete`/`post_delete` when it comes to tracking changes to models, it is included here.

Note that the `sender` for this signal won't be `Appointment` anymore. You should use `Appointment.pianos.through` as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

> Arguments sent with this signal:
>
> `sender`
>
> The intermediate model class describing the `ManyToManyField`. This class is automatically created when a many-to-many field is defined; you can access it using the `through` attribute on the many-to-many field.

A simplified example would be:

```py
@receiver(signals.m2m_changed, sender=Appointment.pianos.through)
def associateAppointmentWithPiano(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    print(f"{sender=} {instance=} {action=})
```

Additional comments from the OP:

> For the benefit of later readers, the action will be `pre_add` first, then a second signal arrives with action being `post_add`. Only at that point is the data in this example available via: `Appointment.pianos.all()`.

Comment: Now how does one petition the powers that be to add-to/clarify the Django docs?  I find them obscure and vague on this issue.

Comment: @Ron See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-documentation/